# Subfield Fixed Under Automorphism of Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across with this literature and I cannot understand the following: "Let $\theta$ be an automorphism of a field $F$ with $|\langle\theta\rangle|=m$. Let $K$ be a subfield of $F$ fixed under $\langle\theta\rangle$." My question is what does $|\langle\theta\rangle|$ represent? Is it the order of the automorphism $\theta$? Also what does it mean for the subfield $K$ to be 'fixed' under $\langle\theta\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\theta\in G={\rm Aut}(F)$, and we write $\langle \theta\rangle$ for the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $\theta$. Then the order of this subgroup is $m$. And $\theta$ fixes $K$ means $\theta(K)=K$ elementwise.

Answer (score 1):

Automorphisms form a group under composition, so $\langle \theta\rangle$ is the subgroup in $\text{Aut}(F)$ generated by $\theta$. Then it means the order of it which is $\theta^m=1$ where the latter is the identity homomorphism.

Being fixed means that for $x\in K$ we have $\theta(x)=x$, which is not neccerily true for all $x\in F$.